# How to make DRF with aliready exists Django app?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to create DRF api.
In my case, I have already existing Django app.
I would like to add api to this existing app.
But I don't know how can I define DRF's models.

There is a using table in the existing app.
So, I run following command

```
python3 manage.py inspectdb
```

I think that I'll reuse those models, but I have a complicated custom user model.
How to create DRF app with already existing Django app ?

Comment: Django Rest Framework uses the models already defined in a Django app, so easiest would be to make the API part of your existing project. Then you can reuse what you have.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know your recommendation is the easiest way. But I would like to separate Django app and DRF app.

Comment: In that case you will have to copy/paste your models from the other app. DRF doesn't work well if you want to directly access the database. Consider using `managed = False` so that your API project doesn't try to do any migrations. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#managed

Comment: May I use ```python3 manage.py inspectdb``` or only copy/paste ? I would like to use same table between DRF app and Django app.

Comment: I would think copying models.py would be less messy, and you'll have access to any extra model functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Your answer is very helpful for me because of I'm a newbie of DRF.